# extract info from a string

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

The following code is working, but I am not able to extract the information I need.
I can use Soup or I need Regular expression?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
mynumber='1234567890'
url="http://www.nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/saveSearchSub.misc?phoneno="+mynumber
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())   

table = soup.findAll("table")[1]
myl=[item.text.strip() for item in table.find_all('td')] 
import re
re.findall(r'is:\s*[^,]*' , myl[1])
```

The expected output is 4 parameters mentioned in the first string of the first slice.

```
['2014-08-07 15:50:00', 'Andhra Pradesh', 'Unitech', '0']
```

(Note the date is changed to Y-M-D)

The string returned looks something like this...

```
[u'is:\n 31-10-2009 01:11\n\n\nService Area : \n Mumbai\n\n\nService Provider :\n Idea\n\n\n\n\n\nYour Preference is :0']
```

Comment: What is the actual string returned? Can you show the contents of `myl[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rely on the `The number is registered in NCPR` header (it is in the `td` tag with class `GridHeader`) and get the next rows via [`find_next_siblings()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mynumber = '1234567890'
url = "http://www.nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/saveSearchSub.misc?phoneno=" + mynumber

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

header = soup.find('td', class_='GridHeader')

result = []
for row in header.parent.find_next_siblings('tr'):
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    try:
        result.append(cells[2].get_text(strip=True))
    except IndexError:
        continue
print result
```

Prints:

```
[u'07-08-2014 15:50', u'Andhra Pradesh', u'Unitech', u'0']
```